# Convert Hyper-V vhdx to iso

Tags: hyper-v, iso-image, vhd, vhdx

If it's possible to convert a linux `Hyper-V` guest VM to an `*.iso` file, then I can create boot able usb from this image file. By google I found following tools:

1. [vhd2iso](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vhd2iso/)
2. [qemu-img](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html)
3. [convert-vhd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/convert-vhd?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Can someone share his experienced in this topic. How to convert `hvdx`->`iso` or `hvdx`->`hvd`->`iso`?

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. ISO images are for optical media. Only _ISOHybrid_ images happen to _also_ be compatible with regular block storage. You simply want a raw disk image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might do this instead to avoid any bug/flaw in any of the conversion tool:

1. Create an attach another VHDX to the VM
2. Attach a live iso to the VM and boot that instead of the installation
3. Partition and format the virtual disk attached in step 1 as NTFS or exFAT and mount the filesystem
4. Use `dd` or even just `cat` to dump a raw image of the virtual disk where the installation resides to the filesystem mounted in step 3; you might even optionally use `tee` additionally to perform a checksum (e.g., `sha1sum` on-the-fly
5. Unmount and shutdown; detach the VHDX that contains the image from the VM and attach it to the host; optionally perform a checksum (with 7-zip or whatever) and compare with the one you got in step 4

Then you can use whatever writer tool you like on Windows to write the raw image to a USB flash drive.

If you have set up SMB share or so on the host, you can probably dump it directly over the virtual network to a volume on your host instead.

It might even be possible to attach the VHDX of the installation (in read-only mode) to the host and perform a direct drive-to-drive clone. I'm not familiar with tools on Windows though so I don't know if there's one can do that.

Note that ISO as in ISO9660 has nothing to do with any of the above or your story / case.